# How to open a file and store data into a linked list structure

Tags: c++, file, linked-list, structure

I have a function `buildList` where I am supposed to open a given file named "studentFile1.txt" and use an overloaded operator to read in data from a file. I am supposed to save all the data as a linked list where each student's info is a node. But I can't seem to open the file for some reason. This is the function `buildList`

```
{
    ifstream file;
    file.open("studentFile1.txt");

    Student temp;     // temporary struct Student object

    if (!file)
        cout << "Can not open file\n";
    while (file >> temp)
    {
        if (list.insert(temp) == false)
            cout << "Insert did not work\n";
    }
}
```

And this is the overloaded operator >> function

```
istream &operator>>(istream &istr, Student &obj)
{
    ifstream file;
    file.open("staudentFile1.txt");

    if (!file)
        cout << "Can not open file.\n";
    while (file)
    {
        istr >> obj.id;
        istr.ignore();
        istr.getline(obj.name, 50, '\n');
        istr >> obj.gpa;
        istr >> obj.major;
    }

    return istr;
}
```

When I call the `buildList` function it just says "Can not open file" twice. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The overloaded `operator>>` should read from the stream passed as the first argument.

Comment: And most likely the file is not located where your program think it is. Try using a full absolute path instead.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I'm sorry but I don't understand what you mean when you say the overloaded ```operator>>``` should read from the stream passed as the first argument. Overloading operators is new to me and I'm still having trouble wrapping my head around it.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude should i just keep the while loop and remove everything else?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I figured it out thank you!

Comment: Regarding the file location, if you don't know about the term [*working directory*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Working_directory) now is the time to learn.A running program will have a *working directory*, this might be different from the location of the executable. If you're running from an IDE (like e.g. Visual Studio) the working directory is by default the directory of the *project*. The IDE will allow you to modify it.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude To be precise: If you run your code in VisualStudio, the default working directory is the output directory for the executable. However, there is an option in Project Settings / Debugging to modify the initial working directory. (I'm quite sure about this because setting the working directory to the project (source) folder is what I usually adjust before I start debugging.) ;-)

Answer (score 0):

When you write file.open("studentfile1.txt") the executable assumes that the file is in the **same** directory as the executable. Check that they are. As for the remainder of the code you have already opened the file  outside the operator overload you shouldn't do it again. Also remove the while loop as it will keep reading until the end of the file so you will read a single record and all the others would be empty.

```
 istream &operator>>(istream &istr, Student &obj)
    {
            istr >> obj.id;
            istr.ignore();
            istr.getline(obj.name, 50, '\n');
            istr >> obj.gpa;
            istr >> obj.major;
    
        return istr;
    }
int main(){
   Student s;
   ifstream file;
   file.open("staudentFile1.txt");
    
   if (!file)
            cout << "Can not open file.\n";
   else {
       while(file>>s)list.insert(s);
   }
   
}
```

Comment: "[T]he executable assumes that the file is in the same directory as the executable" is wrong. All relative paths are from the [*working directory*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Working_directory) of the process, which might be a path very different from where the executable is located.

Comment: in general but most of the time it is invoked from the same directory. e.g. ./a.out for unix and for MSVC++ it is the same